# PHP convert text to variable (html dom)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to convert a string to a variable. The string passes by parameter to a function.

```
public function get($url, $mainclass, $title){
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);

    foreach($html->find(".$mainclass") as $div){
        $title_ = $title;
        /*
               $title_ should get
               $title_ = $div->children(0)->alt;
            */
        return $title;
    }
}
```

So, to call the function:

```
echo $crawl->get("url","description", '$div->children(0)->alt');
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

I need to pass the entire `$div->..` and not only the tag `alt` because it can differs. Sometimes I can pass `$div->children(0)->children(2)->children(1)->alt`

Comment: You could use `eval`, but it's highly discouraged. `$title_ = eval($title);`

Comment: Thanks but I do think my approach isn't the best. I've changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `$div->children(0)->alt`

Comment: I don't have the $div initialized..which means it's going to give error.